# Group by with condition using r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame df where I need to do the group by column A and condition is if column B value is yes and column C value is C then final column value will be C else final column value is U.

```
A=c("w","x","w","z")
B=c("yes","No","yes","No")
C=c("C","U","C","U")

df <- data.frame(A,B,C)

final=c("C","U","C","U")

A=c("w","x","w","z")
B=c("yes","No","yes","No")
C=c("C","U","C","U")

DF <- data.frame(A,B,C,U)
```

My resulting data frame will be DF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  mutate(final = if(any(B == 'yes')) 'C' else 'U') 
  #Without if/else
  #mutate(final = c('U', 'C')[any(B == 'yes') + 1])  

# A     B     C     final
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 w     yes   C     C    
#2 x     No    U     U    
#3 w     yes   C     C    
#4 z     No    U     U
```

If there are many conditions to check you can use `case_when` :

```
df %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  mutate(final = case_when(any(B == 'yes') ~'C',
                          TRUE ~ 'U'))
```

Comment: It is working. Thank You.